# через Класс создан тип, что имеет стрин и вектор, как вписать вектор

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

проблема заключаеться в то, что я хз как записать нулевой вектор в созданом типе через класс

```
 class nameValues
{
    nameValues();
    nameValues(const std::string& s, const std::vector<int>& v) :
        itsName(s),itsValues(v)
    {}
    nameValues(const std::string& s) :
        itsName(s), itsValues(0)
    {}
    void setValue(const int&); 
    void print() const; 
    std::string getName() const;  
    //void setName(const std::string&);
    //std::vector<int> getValue() const;
private:

    std::string itsName;
    std::vector<int> itsValues;
};
void nameValues::setValue(const int& val)
{
    itsValues.push_back(val);
}
void nameValues::print() const
{ 
    
}
std::string nameValues::getName()const
{
    return itsName;
}

int main()
{
    nameValues week(const std::string&);//, const std::vector<int>&);
    std::vector<nameValues> daysScores(8);
    daysScores[0] = week("Montag");
    daysScores[1] = week("Dinstag");
}
```

что нужно дописать после Montag в `daysScores[0] = week("Montag");` чтобы он правильно заработал (0 не подходит, думал через другой конструктор где будет только стрин и вектор будет сам инициализироватся, тоже не вышло)

Answer (score 2):

Итак, ваш код...

```
nameValues week(const std::string&);//, const std::vector<int>&);
```

Это - объявление функции `week` от строки, которая возвращает `nameValues`.

```
daysScores[0] = week("Montag");
```

Присваивание результата вызова функции элементу вектора. Самой функции нигде нет, заметим. Но и это еще не все. При создании вектора вы говорите, что он будет заполнен восемью элементами `nameValues`, которые должны быть созданы с помощью конструктора по умолчанию. И это было бы нормально, но конструктор-то у вас `private` (как все члены класса по умолчанию), и недоступен!

Значит, как минимум, надо добавить `public`:

```
class nameValues
{
public:
    nameValues() {};
    nameValues(const std::string& s, const std::vector<int>& v) :
```

Компилируется. Но `week` только объявлена, но тела ее нет - и вы получаете ошибку линковки.

Я не знаю, если вы хотите *именно некоторую функцию* `week` - тогда напишите ее, и все заработает. Если это ошибка - то, вероятно, вы хотели (ох, как же трудно отвечать на вопросы партизан, которые решили умереть, но не выдать фашистам, которыми считают отвечающих, свои тайны - например, что должна делать программа...) написать что-то вроде

```
daysScores[0] = nameValues("Montag");
daysScores[1] = nameValues("Dinstag");
```

Вот так и компилируется, и линкуется, ну, а дальше думайте сами - то ли это, что вы хотели, или нет...

Comment: спасибо, забыл про паблик :) а так програма должна иметь клас nameValues и сохранять день недели и во второй ячейки вектор, где должны будут сохраняться очки